# Command 'SFDX: Create Project' resulted in an error (command 'sfdx.force.project.create' not found)

Tags: visual-studio, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, lwc

While creating a new sfdx project in VS Code I am getting an error saying error resulted in the command.
I have installed all the necessary extension packages in VS code. Both Salesforce CLI and VS code are up to date.I uninstalled both salesforce CLI and VS code and installed it again, yet the issue is unresolved. Kindly help me with this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8vNL.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the SFDX CLI installed is in a local instance and not a global instance.
On your Command or Terminal Window try:

```
npm install --global sfdx-cli
```